# How to run Go compiler from another Go application

Tags: go, compilation

Are there any options to run Go compiler and build some package from another Go application without resorting to `os/exec` interfaces? Does Go toolchain provides any API for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Go toolchain provides any API for that?

No.